# CSS selectors with Dashing and Rickshaw

Tags: css, rickshaw, dashing

So I have a number of different graphs running on [Dashing](http://dashing.io/) using a single '[Rickshaw](https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614023)' widget. I would like to use a CSS selector to define the x-axis view. I currently have it set up like this...

It dashboard.erb:

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="6" data-sizey="6">
  <div id="weekly" data-id="etvvrb" data-view="Rickshawgraph" data-title="Weekly ETV reach" data-moreinfo="Week commencing" data-color-scheme="rainbow" data-renderer="line" data-x-axis="weekly"></div>
</li>
```

This defines a DIV ID for the name of the selector in CSS, in the CSS we have...

```
  .x_tick {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    fill: $tick-color;

    .title {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: $tick-color;
      opacity: 0.5;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
  }

  #weekly.x_tick  {   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    fill: $tick-color;

      .title {
      font-size: 9px;
      color: $tick-color;
      opacity: 0.5;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      writing-mode:tb-rl;
      -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
      -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
      white-space:nowrap;
      display:block;
      bottom:0;
      width:0.5px;
      height:20px;
    }
  }
```

Essentially I would assume that it would read the ID and use the differing CSS for that ID, but it seems to ignore it completely. I have a feeling that the ID is simply not being passed as I would expect and I'm not really sure why.

If anybody has any background in doing this especially in using Dashing, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If Sass isn't the problem, then only provide the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out.

Dashing will generate a class object which is based on both the data-id and data-view tags (probably via JS but I may be wrong there).

This will come out looking something like widget-data-view.data-id.

This means that you can create a new class in your CSS document using the element generated by JS. In my case, this would look something like:

```
   .widget-rickshawgraph {
       /* CSS stuff */
    }

   .widget-rickshawgraph.DATA-ID {
        .x_tick > .title {
      /* CSS overwrite */
   }
```

Hope that makes sense. Thanks :)